# How can I access a nested class object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm using the node scheduler & it creates an object like so:

```
{
  recurs: true,
  year: null,
  month: null,
  date: null,
  dayOfWeek: null,
  hour: null,
  minute: Range { start: 0, end: 59, step: 2 },
  second: 0 
}
```

How can I access the `minute.Range.step` value?

When I use `minute.Range.step`, node throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'step' of undefined
```

I've also tried `minutes.Range["step"]` which is the same as what I tried above.

Comment: `minute.step` or `minute["step"]`.

Comment: `.minute.step`? Why are you using `Range`?

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally typed the wrong value when writing up my question @Amadan - I edited the question to show what I actually tried

Comment: @Oriol Tipped me off, thanks. I thought you had to access the properties via the `Range` object.

Comment: `minute` *is* the Range object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're logging objects in Node, a class name immediately preceding an object tells you want class *that object* is.

So in your case, when Node logs

```
{
   ...
   minute: Range { start: 0, end: 59, step: 2 },
   ...
}
```

It actually means that the object you're printing is a plain object, which has a property `minute` (of type `Range`) with its own properties `start`, `end` and `step`.

**So to refer to `step`, you have to use `minute.step`.**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I will delete my answer as yours goes into a bit more detail :)